# MSN bot appending wrong parameters to URLs

Tags: search-engine, bots, googlebot, msn

On my site http://www.mustseeindia.com/places-around-bangalore"" is valid URL.

While crawling, MSN bot is appending a string to it and there by causing a crawl error.

**String appended by MSN bot** - "&layout=button_count&show_faces=false&width=80;&action=like&font&colorscheme=light&height=25"

**Wrong URL generated by MSN bot** - http://www.mustseeindia.com/places-around-bangalore&layout=button_count&show_faces=false&width=80;&action=like&font&colorscheme=light&height=25

This is preventing 1000's of pages on my site from being crawled by MSN, how can I handle this ?

Answer (score 1):

That is basic URL manipulation and I don't see anything tricky on your site (although [markup *is* full of errors](http://html5.validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mustseeindia.com%2Fplaces-around-bangalore)), so I suspect that wasn't a real msnbot, but some lame spambot/harvester that cloaked as msnbot.